# Adding a DIV row to an existing row

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

can anyone please advise what may be wrong with my script below?

It should look for the last DIV with #objec in the class name, and then look for the last input element within the DIV, then add a new DIV with incremented ID/Names below the one there already.  I think this is the line which is going wrong:

```
var name = $("#objec:last>input").attr("name");
```

The code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/mtait/9MbQH/6/

...and below.

Thank you,

Mark

```
<label id="add_tag"> 
     Click me to add a new row
</label> 


<div class="objec">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
            <input class="span4" data-val="true" data-val-required="Objective&#32;is&#32;required" id="Objectives_7__objective" name="Objectives[7].objective" type="text" value="Timecard Completion" />
        </div>
     </div>
</div>


$(document).ready(function() {
var re = /\[(.*?)\]/;
$("#add_tag").click(function() {
    var name = $("#objec:last>input").attr("name");
    var m = re.exec(name);
    var itemNumber = parseInt(m[1]) + 1;
    var $newdiv1 = $('<div class="objec"><div class="row"><div class="span4"><input class="span4" data-val="true" data-val-required="Objective&#32;is&#32;required" id="Objectives_' + itemNumber + '__objective" name="Objectives[' + itemNumber + '].objective" type="text" value="..." /></div></div>');
    $(".objec:last").after($newdiv1);
    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: yu dont get any better name for class  other than  objec and row !! are you getting any error now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you want this:

```
var name = $(".objec:last input").attr("name");
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9MbQH/9/)

Read about the differences between [**Descendant combinator**](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#descendant-combinators) and [**Child combinators**](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators).

Comment: Thankyou - it was the > - when replaced with a space, it worked!  I'll mark as answer when SO allows. Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 1):

this type of usage is for ID  . If objec is an ID you can use the below

```
 $("#objec:last>input")
```

in your case its a class name

so try

```
  $(".objec")
```

Comment: Didn't work - but thank you for trying - below answer did however.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, I think you're supposed to use the "." selector when referring to a class vs. an id.
ex/ $(".objec:last>input").attr("name");